# Is `javax.inject` available in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, javax.inject

I have been working on a Spring Boot project (version 2.0.4.RELEASE).
Following is the build.gradle

```
plugins {

    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'

    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.6.RELEASE'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

I imported the project to eclipse by creating the eclipse config files using eclipse plugin in Gradle.

I used `javax.inject.Inject` annotation without having to add an additional dependency, and ran the application using eclipse without any issues.

However, when I did a clean build on command line recently, the build failed because it could not find `@Inject`

```
error: cannot find symbol
        @Inject
         ^
```

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Spring does not provide that annotation.  You need to add javax.inject as a dependency.  I'm not sure how you were able to add that annotation without explicitly adding that library.

Comment: It's good to know that spring does not provide the annotation, but I'm curious as to how it was available in the first place.

Comment: @DiliniRajapaksha I am curious too.